# Cmd calendar in Python

Tags: python

I just trying to do python challenges. And part of one is cmd calendar looks that:

```
| M  | T  | W  | Th | F  | S  | Su |
|    |    |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |
|  6 |  7 |  8 |  9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 |
| 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 |
| 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 |    |    |    |
```

In this case, all months has 30 days. I need to do that in iterative way. 
I need to keep start day in variable. Start day should be 0-6 when 0 is Monday, and 6 is Sunday. For example, the month from example variable = 2.

I can't do that but i want to understand it. How can I do that in iterative way?

I tried do that in another way, just using calendar library, but it's not the correct solution.

Can someone help me?

I'm trying something like this right now:

```
print("| M | T | W | Th | F | S | SN |")

i = 0
while i < 6:
    print("| {}  | {}  | {}  | {}  | {}  | {}  | {}  |".format(i,i+1,i+2,i+3,i+4,i+5,i+7))
    i = i+1
```

Comment: Could you provide printing function or you don't have it?

Comment: @PavelAntspovich Im just added what I'm tried now

Comment: Did you think of using the built-in calendar?  https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html

Comment: @martin, its okay because you are completing the challenge but python already provides a built-in ```calendar``` module for these type of operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the best solution, but it works

```py
days = ['M', 'T', 'W', 'Th', 'F', 'S', 'Su']

start_day = 2
month_last_date = 30

print('|', end = ' ')
for day in days:
    print(day, '\t|', end=' ')
print('')

print('|', end = ' ')
for number in range(1, month_last_date + start_day + 1):
    if (number <= start_day):
        print('\t|', end=' ')
    else:       
        print(number - start_day, '\t|', end=' ')
    if (number % 7 == 0):
        print('')
        print('|', end="")
```

output:

```
| M     | T     | W     | Th    | F     | S     | Su    |
|       |       | 1     | 2     | 3     | 4     | 5     |
|6      | 7     | 8     | 9     | 10    | 11    | 12    |
|13     | 14    | 15    | 16    | 17    | 18    | 19    |
|20     | 21    | 22    | 23    | 24    | 25    | 26    |
|27     | 28    | 29    | 30    |
```

**UPD-1** fixed new lines

**UPD-2** fixed date range

Comment: Thanks for answer, is helpful. Now I need to just upgrade it to print 30 numbers

Comment: Ouch, I'll fix it

Comment: I just added start_day to month_last_day. Thank U Pavel

Comment: Just messed range end c: Fixed

Comment: I have a wierd output, not that beautiful like U :D

Comment: @martin, could you provide screenshot?